# ActionLink with HttpMethod=DELETE does not work

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink, http-delete

I try to implement DELETE method for my mvc-application.

There is my link placed in View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Users", new { userId = user.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "DELETE" })
```

There is my controller method:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(string userId)
{
    //...
    return View("Index");
}
```

When I click on Delete-link, I get a 404 error.

In Fiddler I see, that my request perfomed by GET method!
If I execute DELETE request with the same Headers from Fiddler, I get the expected result - my request is coming right into the Delete method.

How can I use `@Ajax.ActionLink` correctly?

P.S.: I want to use only built-in methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure all the Unobtrusive libraries are loaded? An `@Ajax.ActionLink` generates a standard anchor tag. If the JavaScript libraries aren't loaded to handle the click event, you'll get the GET request you see in Fiddler.

Check to see if the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script is included in a bundle that is referenced from your layout page or that you're explicitly loading it on specific pages in a scripts region.

Comment: The next libraries are loaded: Modernizr v2.7.2, jQuery v2.1.0,
jQuery Validation 1.11.1, Bootstrap v3.1.1, jquery validate unobtrusive

Comment: The fact your link click is executing a GET request tells me something isn't handling the click and preventing the default behavior. That suggests a missing library, likely the unobtrusive libs since this is the same thing that happened to me when I failed to add them to my specific views.

Comment: You can try changing the HttpMethod to POST and seeing if that works. If you are still receiving a GET request, I'd point you back to a likely problem with the libs. If it works then we have a better place to start bisecting this problem.

Comment: Doing a little searching just to make sure DELETE is a supported type, this answer suggests others have it working once the right libs are in place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933702/problems-doing-a-proper-http-delete-with-ajax-actionlink

Comment: I found that the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not included in any script bundles. Now everything works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Users", 
  new { userId = user.Id }, 
  new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

I am not sure why you used 'Delete' for the HTTPMethod. Post will send the Id for data you want removed to the server and call the 'Delete' ActionResult specified here      `@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Users",`.